error TS2345: Argument of type `'ISchoolService' `is not assignable to parameter of type `'ServiceDefinition<UntypedServiceImplementation>'`
I generate grpc Typescript code with:
"proto": "npx grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./grpc/client --grpc_out=./grpc/client --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin` -I ./grpc/proto ./grpc/proto/*.proto && npx grpc_tools_node_protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=`which protoc-gen-ts` --ts_out=./grpc/client -I ./grpc/proto ./grpc/proto/*.proto",

and hit the following error:
Services/SchoolService.ts:205:23 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'ISchoolService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ServiceDefinition<UntypedServiceImplementation>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'ISchoolService'.

205     server.addService(SchoolService, new ServerImpl());

Environment

OS name, version and architecture: [e.g. Linux Ubuntu 18.04 amd64] Ubuntu 24.04
Node version [e.g. 8.10.0] 22.4.1
Node installation method [e.g. nvm] apt
If applicable, compiler version [e.g. clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4] g++ 13.2.0
Package name and version [e.g. gRPC@1.12.0]:

    "grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts": "^5.3.3",
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.10.10",

What do I miss?

It's hard to tell without seeing the code that contains the line that the error refers to, but one likely possibility is that you should actually be using SchoolService.service in that line.
